# where to put secure passwords/keys in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

I have a few web services that require secure tokens/keys/passwords to be passed in.  Where should I define these secure values for my rails app to see?  I want the development keys in version control, but don't want the production keys in version control.  How should I set this up?  I'm new to rails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You see the question properly.

Put your `passwords` and `keys` in some yml file excluded from version control.

Then on your production server, create the very same file and symlink your app to it every time you deploy.

EDIT.

Capistrano is almost made to fits these needs:

- put your `yml` files in the `shared` folder
- In your capistrano `deploy.rb`file:

  ```
  after 'deploy' do
    run "ln -s #{shared_path}/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"  
  end
  ```
- to work with yml files: http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file

Comment: Thanks.  So, I would automate this process in a Capistrano script?  And like I said, I'm new.  Where should I create the yml file and where should I load/read it?

Answer (score 4):

apneadiving is right, symlinking the files is a good idea. Another approach is to put the keys in the shell variables, accessible only to the user that runs the app. Then, in your rails app you'll have

```
login = ENV['SERVICE_LOGIN']
password = ENV['SERVICE_PASSWORD']
```

Comment: I think this approach works better with Heroku, or easier at least... Thanks.

Comment: +1. Also, check out the following for a great way to manage these on a  per-project basis: https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv

Answer (score 0):

As of Rails 4.1.0, check out [secrets.yml](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2014/4/8/Rails-4-1/).