# Thin server not loading environment variables with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, environment-variables, capistrano, thin

I'm deploying my rails app with capistrano and using the thin server. I have 2 env vars for my mailer username and password defined in ~/.bash_profile with `export SMTP_USERNAME=...`.

When I ssh to the server and try to send emails from the rails console it works fine but it looks like they are not loaded by thin when I run `cap deploy` or any other command.

What's the correct way to define them? I've seen some posts where they suggest to define them directly in the `config/environments/production.rb` or in some other file related to the code itself. I was trying to avoid that for security reasons.

**UPDATE**: I tried to use a yml file to store this but I ran into this problem:

I created a new file `email_config.rb` in `config/initializers`. Its content is:

```
EMAIL_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/email.yml")[RAILS_ENV]
```

In `config/email.yml` I have:

```
production:
    username: username
    password: password
```

In my `config/environments/production.rb` I have:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  authentication: :plain,
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: EMAIL_CONFIG[:username],
  password: EMAIL_CONFIG[:password]
}
```

Now the problem is that initializers are loaded after `environments.rb` and if I put the definition of the `EMAIL_CONFIG` variable just before my email configuration, then the `RAILS_ROOT` variable is not define.

Answer (score 0):

Like you're saying, not a god idea to save a password directly in the production.rb. A better option would be to reference them from shell variables (closer to your current setup) or from a yaml file (what I do personally).  You can find more information in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245284/where-to-put-secure-passwords-keys-in-a-rails-app)